# Run buildfile with parameters under Linux

Tags: ant

I created an Ant task that runs buildfile (dfs-build.xml) with parameters.  It works well under  OS Windows. But, I would like ANT task runs under Linux.  Any ideas?

```
<exec executable="cmd">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg value="${ant.basedir}\bin\ant -Dproperty.files.dir=${property.files.dir} -Dbasedir=${antscripts.basedir}/../DocumentumCoreProject/dfs6.7 -Dmodule.name=rbacs -f ${antscripts.basedir}\sub_ANTs\Create_EAR_WAR\dfs-build.xml generate"/>
</exec>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exec task is simpler under Linux:

```
<exec executable="${ant.basedir}\bin\ant" osfamily="unix">
   <arg value="-Dproperty.files.dir=${property.files.dir} -Dbasedir=${antscripts.basedir}/../DocumentumCoreProject/dfs6.7 -Dmodule.name=rbacs -f ${antscripts.basedir}\sub_ANTs\Create_EAR_WAR\dfs-build.xml generate"/>
</exec>
```

Another cross-platform option is to run the build within the same ANT process

```
<subant antfile="{antscripts.basedir}\sub_ANTs\Create_EAR_WAR\dfs-build.xml" target="generate">
    <property name="property.files.dir" value="${property.files.dir}"/>
    <property name="basedir" value="${antscripts.basedir}/../DocumentumCoreProject/dfs6.7"/>
    <property name="module.name" value="rbacs"/>
</subant>
```